# How to tackle different user types with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems, devise

I have 2 types of Users. A Company and a Worker.

How do I manage it in devise where I have only 1 User?

I want to create 2 registration pages for Company and Worker, but I only want 1 table which stores user information such as Users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd comment on codevoice's ample response, but I don't have enough rep yet.

From documentation that codevoice linked to:

> If you have more than one role in your
>   application (such as "User" and
>   "Admin"), you will notice that Devise
>   uses the same views for all roles.
>   Fortunately, Devise offers an easy way
>   to customize views. All you need to do
>   is set "config.scoped_views = true"
>   inside
>   "config/initializers/devise.rb".
>
> After doing so, you will be able to
>   have views based on the role like
>   "users/sessions/new" and
>   "admins/sessions/new". If no view is
>   found within the scope, Devise will
>   use the default view at
>   "devise/sessions/new". You can also
>   use the generator to generate scoped
>   views:
>
> ...

So it's possible to have one set of views for all devise models, just put them in devise/sessions/*.

Answer (score 1):

first prepare models then
just register `devise_for` both models

```
devise_for :companies
devise_for :workers
```

in routes

here you have example: [devise manual github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Comment: What should i then do in the view? Will there not by 2 login in pages? <% if company_signed_in? %>
    Signed in as <%= current_company.email %> . Not you?
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_company_session_path %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", new_company_registration_path %> or <%= link_to "sign in", new_company_session_path %>
  <% end %> I only want 1 login page

Comment: yup something like this- you will have `current_companyz and `current_worker` and so on ... check `rake routes | grep session` to find out paths

Comment: How do i make 1 login page where you can login as worker and company. I dont want them to be seperate.

Comment: you should make your own login page

Comment: Is there i way that i can have i can make a tabel Users wish stores all login informationen. Instead of haveing 2 separate tabels that have columns for the login information?